# Adding a child of a child gives a 500 error

Tags: php, xml

Everything works, kind of!

I can add a child node and save the XML okay.
I can then add a child node to the one above and save it again as okay.

My problem is that when I add a child node, and then try and add a child node to the first child, I get a 500 error!

I'm sure I've missed something, but can't see where.

```
$customerPath = $xml->xpath('//customers//customer[@name="'.$customerName.'"]');
if ( !$customerPath ) {
    $customerAdd = $xml->customers->addChild('customer');
    $customerAdd->addAttribute('name', $customerName);      
}


// CHECK IF HOST EXISTS

$hostPath = $xml->xpath('//customers//customer[@name="'.$customerName.'"]//host[@name="'.$hostName.'"]');
if ( !$hostPath ) {
    $hostAdd = $customerPath->addChild('host');
    $hostAdd->addAttribute('name', $hostName);        
}
```

Comment: What is the specific error you get, 500 just means the server encountered an error but doesn't tell us anything about what the error is. One thing that I can think of just looking at your code is that you never actually set `$customerPath` if it didn't originally exist which would mean that your second `if` statement will fail b/c `$customerPath` would be `null`.

Comment: Thanks, the response was calling an, which kind of screwed things up when I tried to add the array variable to the main XML

Answer (score 0):

Problem with response which was an array rather that a string.

Comment: This should be a comment not a straightforward answer.